# Why can't I save a file as a csv?

Tags: csv

So I downloaded this file off the web and its in CSV format but saved as a txt. It has every thing separated by commas and everything but I am having trouble making it a CSV file. When I go to "save as", to try to save it as a CSV, I don't see the option to save it as a CSV.

Comment: That probably depends on the MIME type that is returned with the file.

Comment: Please provide more information - what software do you used? is this programming question?

Comment: "save as" in what? What happens when you just change the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer not knowing what software you are using.

Try to open the file using Microsoft Excel and then save it as CSV.

If Excel won't open it, then copy-paste the data from the text file to a new Excel workbook in top left cell then use the function "Text to Columns" located in the "Data" tab.

The wizard will then help you convert your data from any CSV format which you will then be able to save as CSV file.

Comment: Or, you know, just rename the file to `*.csv`.

Comment: He might not have enabled the option in windows that shows the files extensions, thus preventing him to change it. But still, good point.

Comment: *If* OP is using Windows to begin with. I'm not a Windows user, but *surely* there's still a way to change a file's extension?

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSV file in Notepad. Save as `AllFiles`, and `filename.csv`. Now this `*.txt` file will exist alongside a new file `filename.csv` in the same directory. Now you can open this csv file in excel. (make sure you choose all files here also otherwise the csv file won't be visible)